Chrome json viewer for websocket network responses (Firefox already has it builtin)
I need to check websocket responses for our web application. However, chrome does not show it under Network>defaulthub (101) properly.
Firefox does have it built-in but I use mostly Chrome. Is there any add-on or workaround which I can use in the chrome developer tools.
Currently, I copy the response in Notepad++ and see there.
[Firefox Screenshot]
[Chrome Screenshot]
I tried several json viewer add-ons on chrome but they did not work.
